# Items hidden when added to HyperLinkButton

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, hyperlink

The items below show up normally when I do not have them inside the HyperlinkButton.
However, when I add them to the HyperlinkButton, they become invisible.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/ViewChallenge.aspx">
        <HyperlinkButton.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding Path=Challenge.Image}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
                <StackPanel Width="311">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Challenge.Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="ViewUser.aspx" >
                        <HyperlinkButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=User.Username}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Content>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                 </StackPanel>
             </StackPanel>
        </HyperlinkButton.Content>
    </HyperlinkButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the [Hyperlink button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) only supports text. For example:

```
<HyperlinkButton Height="100" Width="300">
    Hello World
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Maybe you should use a Button control and set a Control template and enter the XAML you mentioned above inside. It makes more sense in my opinion. Try this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">      
            <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding Path=Challenge.Image}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>      
            <StackPanel Width="311">      
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Challenge.Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>          
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=User.Username}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>      
             </StackPanel>      
         </StackPanel>   
</ControlTemplate>
```

And simply set the template for your button like so:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}" Click="myButton_Click"/>
```

And then do the navigation inside the click event.